# KDE/Ubuntu 21.04: accidentally killed the taskbar "window"

Tags: kubuntu, taskbar

In KSysGuard there's a tool to kill a window by clicking on it. On the way to kill the window I wanted, I accidentally clicked on the taskbar, which is now gone. How do I turn it back on without rebooting?

Comment: You could try logout & login again (ie. re-starting the KDE session)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to run from the terminal is

```
kstart5 plasmashell
```

That brought the taskbar back.